# Fastest way to clone a 128gb usb stick with over 100k files

Tags: usb, usb-flash-drive, file-transfer, clone, usb-storage

I have a 128gb usb 2.0 stick and it has many small files. In total about 100k files and it takes at least 6 hours just to copy all these files onto another usb stick. What is the fastest way to clone this usb stick to the same exact usb stick? Is there such a thing as a sector to sector copy without having to copy files over one at a time? I think this is why its taking a long time. Or is there another solution to speed this copying up?

Comment: These many files would take time, how about compressing with WinRAR using Store option it excludes compression, but it will still take some time for these many files. But once created you can transfer the compressed file far more quickly. Second option is to use some image creation tools to create a .iso file they are also quick. And .iso file then can be transported.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there such a thing as a sector to sector copy without having to copy files over one at a time?

Yes, many disk cloning programs support doing sector-level copies while skipping the "unused" parts of the disk. I don't have any specific names for Windows, however, on Linux there is `ntfsclone` for NTFS specifically and `partclone` for a lot of other filesystems including FAT32 and exFAT. They read the filesystem's "free space bitmap" or equivalent, then use it to skip sectors.

But at USB 2.0 speeds, even a *full* 128 GB sector copy (e.g. using `cp` or `dd`) should take less than 2 hours at 30 MB/s. It is likely to be faster than a file-level copy as it can work with larger chunks of data than the individual files (and the associated metadata updates for each...)